# Cannot get the value if the sharepoint column type is "Person" - Python

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365api

I am trying to extract a list from Sharepoint. The thing is that if the column type is "Person or Group" Python show me a KeyError but if the column type is different I can get it.

[image: Column types in SharePoint]

This is my code to to get the values:

```
print("Item title: {0}, Id: {1}".format(item.properties["Title"], item.properties['AnalystName']))
```

And Title works but AnalystName does not. both are the internal names in the sharepoint.

Comment: have zero experience with python but if you are using csom, could you just try `(item.properties['AnalystName']).LookupValue`. basically this field returns a user object that when loaded exposes different properties

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: The difference is that a user column returns a sub-object with multiple properties about the referenced user, while columns like Title return a scalar string value.  If you can post the code you are using to retrieve the data from SharePoint it would be easier for us to show you how to access the user object values.

Comment: See my answer please

Answer (score 0):

```
authcookie = Office365('https://xxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com', username='xxxxxxxxx', password='xxxxxxxxx').GetCookies()
site = Site('https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/qualityassuranceteam', authcookie=authcookie)
new_list = site.List('Process Review - Customer Service Opt In/Opt Out')
query = {'Where': [('Gt', 'Audit Date', '2020-02-16')]}
sp_data = new_list.GetListItems(fields=['App ID', 'Analyst Name', 'Team Member Name', "Team Member's Supervisor Name",
                                        'Audit Date', 'Event Date (E.g. Call date)', 'Product Type', 'Master Contact Id',
                                        'Location', 'Team member read the disclosure?', 'Team member withheld the disclosure?',
                                        'Did the team member take the correct action?', 'Did the team member notate the account?',
                                        'Did the team member add the correct phone number?', 'Comment (Required)',
                                        'Modified'], query=query)
#print(sp_data[0])

final_file = '' #Create an empty File
num = 0
for k in sp_data:
    values = sp_data[num].values()
    val = "|".join(str(v).replace('None', 'null') for v in values) + '\n'
    num += 1
    final_file += val
file_name = 'test.txt'
with open(file_name, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
     file.write(final_file)
```

So right now I´m getting what I want but there is a problem. When a Column is empty it skips the column instead of bring an empty space. for example:

---

### col-1  |  col-2  |  col-3  |

### HI   |   10    |    8    |

### Hello |         |    7    |

So in this table the row 1 is full so it will bring me evertything as: 
HI|10|8
but the second row brings me 
Hello|7 
and I need Hello||7

Answer (score 0):

Person Fields are getting parsed with different names from items
Ex: UserName gets changed to UserNameId and UserNameString

That is the reason for 'KeyError' since the items list is not having the item

Use Below code to get the person field values

```
#Python Code
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

site_url = "enter sharepoint url"
sp_list = "eneter list name" 
ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(UserCredential("username","password"))
tasks_list = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(sp_list)
items = tasks_list.items.get().select(["*", "UserName/Id", "UserName/Title"]).expand(["UserName"]).execute_query()
for item in items:  # type:ListItem
    print("{0}".format(item.properties.get('UserName').get("Title")))
```